# How to handle multiple jLists with one ListSelectionEvent

Tags: java, listener, jlist

I have three jLists in my class `frmMain`. I have created a class called `ListActions`.  The code below is working for one jList.  It returns the value clicked for one jList.

How do I distinguish between the three other jList?   Or do I need to create a seperate class for each listener?

I need to perform an action based on which jList was clicked. I attempted to see if I could access the variable name of the jList that was clicked, but couldn't find a way to do this...

```
class ListActions implements ListSelectionListener {

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {

    if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) {

        JList list = (JList) evt.getSource();

        int iSelectedDatabase = list.getSelectedIndex();
        Object objSelectedDatabase = list.getModel().getElementAt(iSelectedDatabase);
        String sSelectedDatabase = objSelectedDatabase.toString();


        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, sSelectedDatabase);

    }
}
```

}

Thanks,
- Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) inherits from [Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

Therefore, you can use the [getName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29) method to get the name of your `Component` and know which one has been called.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it earlier but I was getting an error, because I was using .toString() by mistake... Now its working..